# Large Html Code - page response time very slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a **web application** where I have to **display an html table** with around **400 rows and 9 columns**.

There's lot going on in the application...( large number of events, different views ) 
It has around **1700 lines of Jquery Code.** Although i have **optimised Jquery code** to the extent i read in various articles using - selectors caching, using proper selectors, using proper event delegation,chaining, referring to jsperf to test almost every method, selectors i have used etc etc. Although the responsiveness of the page has increased some extent but still its far from what is required. ( strict performance requirements )

**Question:** For every **table cell (td )** there's a click event which opens the bootstrap modal. If the no. of **rows in the table are 50** Modal **opening time is 50.32ms** and if the **table rows** are around **400 the modal opening time is 700ms** ( measuring time using console.time ). How the **number of rows in my table ( html code ) affecting modal opening time.??? how can i fix this??

--> this is the code i am using for opening modal

```
$('#mainTable).on('click','.cell',function(){
       cellzoom(this);
 }); 

function cellzoom(obj,e,date) {
    console.time('cellzoom:')
    cellModal();
    console.timeEnd('cellzoom:')
}


function cellModal(){
//  $(mainloader).show();
    console.time('cellModal:')
    $(cellview).modal('show');
    console.timeEnd('cellModal:')
}
```

P.S : i Cannot use pagination

Anyone who has dealt with large data set and large amount of jquery code and things(tools) they did to optimise their code...any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What is your selector like for the click event?

Comment: Is there any specific function that's slow? You mentioned a click event getting slower as the dataset expands, that makes me think the slowness is in your algorithm for showing the modal itself. It sounds like your code for showing the modal is dependent on the size of the data such as maybe it's looping over every cell when you click. Can you post the code related to that?

Comment: @kirk : please check the edit...meanwhile...How can check the time distribution of events that are taking place in my function....i tried using chrome timeline...honestly it went over my head

Comment: I don't understand your cellZoom() function. Why do you pass 3 parameters and don't use them?  And then it only calls another function?  Is there something else that you've edited out?

Comment: @ EatPeanutButter - yes i have edited out some code for sake of clarity....but cellzoom function does;nt open the bootstrap modal....cellModal () function does it!!!

Comment: The jQuery selectors you are using in cellzoom are probably the culprit. Try commenting them out and see if it's faster without them. You'll need to probably rework the way you get the values instead of using find() which is why it gets slower as the dataset expands

Comment: @kirk..thanks for your reply...I think i found the answer...the problem is with the $(cellview).modal('show') function ( bootstrap native function for opening/showing modal ) ....when i tried to implement the modal myself....i.e $(cellview).show()....the modal opened up in 4ms as compared to 700ms before.....although I am missing some extra features which bootstrap modal provides like...pressing esc to close the modal...I think i am better off with less features and faster time....may be later i can implement them myself!!!

Answer (score 1):

It can possible depend on your CSS for the modal. If it has a lot of shadow, gradient etc. then browser can suffer from the large HTML structure and renders the CSS slowly. But if I were you I would also look at the method for showing the modal , like @Kirk wrote